# Display a red asterisk (*) in Django forms

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-forms

I want to change in my form the color of the label_suffix.

I just want to set the '*' in red and leave the rest black. Is this possible or do i have to change something in my HTML?

username = forms.CharField(label="Username",label_suffix='*')

Comment: Just add `required_css_class = 'required'` to your form. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.required_css_class)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Get rid of this - `label_suffix='*'`. We'll write some CSS to display a `*` after the required fields.

First, in your form set an attribute called [`required_css_class`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.required_css_class):

```
class MyForm(...):
    required_css_class = 'required'
```

Django will set a class called `required` in the HTML label and input for the field.

Now, put these lines your css file to display a red asterisk:

```
label.required::after {
    content: ' *';
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: I use the selector `.required > label::after`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that if you've already overriden the change_form.html for your project, you can simply add the css provided by @xyres to the change_form.html with a slight modification as follows to avoid it from conflicting with the admin's already defined CSS:

```
label.required::after {
    content: ' *' !important;
    color: red;
}
```

No need to add `required_css_class = 'required'` to your form for this. Tested with Django 4.0.4