# How can i add a red asterisk (*) in my django-login view?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I allready put the red asterisk (*) in my registration form. (Like xyres told me [a link] [Display a red asterisk (*) in Django forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54353923/display-a-red-asterisk-in-django-forms)). Now i want to do the same in my login form. But i only use the standard Django-Login. My settings.py contains

Do i have to change the default-files in django.contrib.auth?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # Django apps
    'django.contrib.auth', 
    ...]
```

UPDATE:
I tryed to give my urls.py the html like this but it doesn't has an affect on it.

```
     path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'), {'template_name': 'UnserProjekt/accounts/templates/login.html'}),
```

and my login.html i created new

```
  <form class="login" method="POST" action="/login/">
      <h1>LOGIN</h1>

  {% csrf_token %}

  {% for field in form %}
  <style>
      login-form label::after {
    content: ' *';
    color: red;
}
  </style>
  {{ form.field }}
  {% endfor %}

  <li><input type="submit" class="logBut" value="Log in"/></li>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default Django login template

```
  <form class="login" method="POST" action="/login/">

  {% csrf_token %}

  {% for field in form %}
  /// implement custom output here
  {{ form.field }}
  {% endfor %}

  <li><input type="submit" class="logBut" value="Log in"/></li>
  </form>
```

and use it like this

```
url(r'^login/$','django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': '/login.html'})
```

or you can define it with css like in the example you provided, but target the class or id of the field you want to target. A possible example bellow.

```
#login-form label::after {
    content: ' *';
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: but how can i tell the login html to use this css. I don't have defined one, because Django is handling it for me. Or do i have to write a new html and tell it django in urls.py ?

Comment: You have to define your own login HTML and define it in urls as described above.